# Magento 2 installation error Trying to access array offset on the value

Tags: magento2, installation, command

When I try to install Magento 2.4.1 I get this error
Error happened during deploy process: Notice: Trying to access array offset on the value of type null in /home/609563/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Design/Theme/ThemeList.php on line 254

Comment: Are you sure this is a vanilla install with no changes? Or does this already have some customization, such as a custom theme?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you have a `theme.xml` file that is empty. If you have an empty file, the media information will be a null value. Normally, with PHP 7.3 and earlier, you would not get an error when trying to use a null value as an array. But with PHP 7.4, things like this break code execution.

My recommendation is to view each of your codebase's `theme.xml` files and ensure that they have a proper structure. Here is an example of what they should look like:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
    <title>Magento Blank</title>
    <media>
        <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
    </media>
</theme>
```